# Customizing browser to autologin

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser, firefox-addon

I want to modify firefox / chrome to be able to autologin on some websites.Extension like lastpass is not an option since anyone can get  the password easily.

An possible approach

For some specific urls i can send the data via POST automatically to auto login

How can i achieve that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Firefox you would force populate the password field with the user name and password from password manager, and then login.

You will need to use a pageMod - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/page-mod - this allows you to listen to page loads